# Joomla 3.6 Template Creation - Article Titles and Bodies

Tags: templates

I want my template to display Article Titles and Bodies with the following markup:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="section-head">
    <h3>My Title Goes Here</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="section-body">
    <p>Body goes here</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum etc... </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this? All the tutorials I've found have been too basic and do not cover sufficient detail any more than

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Which will contain the whole article, leaving me with no control over markup.

Comment: https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Comment: thanks for the tip. I have used the technique described to override the com_content/views/featured/tmpl/default_item.php file in my template at templatename/html/com_content/views/featured/default_ite.php but it does not work

Comment: found it, i needed to delete the views directory as well

Comment: @NickJ or Neil please add this as a full answer below and mark it as accepted;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override Joomla! template.

Here are some details about overriding Joomla! template:

https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

You can also check basics about creating Joomla! templates:

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_basic_Joomla!_template

And here is a complete section about Joomla templates:

https://docs.joomla.org/Portal:Template_Development